# Scheduling of planned orders while respecting certain stock levels

Tags: modeling, reference-request, scheduling, inventory, terminology

I am searching for the academic name of the problem of computing a valid schedule for planned order. More precisely, The problem consists of: list of orders **O**, available vehicle per day **K**, and the quantity of stock replenishment per day. My goal is to compute a schedule of order *o* delivered at day *j* while making sure that stock is not below or above critical levels.

Comment: Often I just start modeling (e.g. as a MIP). That is a good exercise to get a better understanding of the problem. If there is literature, I often find that to be easier to read, after I have been playing with the model a bit.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! The problem isn't hard to model, I think, but I am very surprised that I can't find it in the literature. I would think that it is a common problem in the industry. Scheduling of orders of different products on a month horizon. Such that the stock, which has a consistent inflow from my production, stays always between safe levels. Cant make all deliveries on day one for example cause not enough stock, can't let it too long because my stock will become full and products would be destroyed

Comment: Many or even most of the models I have worked on have no name in the literature that exactly covers what they are doing. Shoehorning a model to fit some existing model can lead to less natural modeling. By default, I try to stay close to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the *inventory routing problem*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but it's a little different I think. I am not trying to optimize the routing. The vehicle part is to say that I can ship only a limited quantity per day. It's more like a nurse's scheduling problem, where each order has to be assigned to a particular day. However, the number of orders that can be delivered per day is constrained by the limited number of vehicles, and the available stock. Stocks are replenished every two days.

Comment: I don't control the stock, stock replenishing is input, I just need to make schedule for the orders so that the stock is not overcapacitated neither empty. The stock is the ouput of a production process that cannot be changed. I search something like shipping schedueling with respect to inventory level constraints, but didn't found the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "*drayage scheduling problem* " might open a window for you.